# GCC's __attribute__ does not work for struct member in LLVM

Tags: c, struct, attributes, llvm, llvm-clang

When using GCC's `__attribute__` I noticed that attributes are ignored when used in a struct.

```
struct MyFCNPointers {
    void (*MyFCNPointer)(const char *str, ...) __attribute__((__format__(printf, 1, 2)));
};

struct MyFCNPointers MyFCNPointers;

// Gives no warning at all
MyFCNPointers.MyFCNPointer("Hello %s");
```

However, this works:

```
void (*MyFCNPointer)(const char *str, ...) __attribute__((__format__(printf, 1, 2)));

// Gives the expected warning
MyFCNPointer("Hello %s");
```

Is there a reason for this? And more importantly is there a workaround for this? (I use a struct to give functions a namespace. Example: `X.Thread.Mutex__alloc()`)

**EDIT:**

`gcc -v` gives

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both give warnings with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall` and both don't without `-Wall`. Which version do you use and how is `gcc` invoked?

Comment: Version of gcc: `4.2.1` (this is what I got through the `__GNUC__` macro), compiler is `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`

Comment: @mafso You are right, on my Ubuntu Server (GCC 4.6.3) it works. But why it doesn`t work on my Mac with Xcode 5?

Comment: `clang` is really a different compiler and it is only emulating gcc features.

Comment: [In the Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) they refer to the GCC doc, looks like it should work in theory. I think, you should tag your question `clang` and mention your version etc (what you've wrote in the comment). And hopefully someone knows more details...